# Regarding C typedef struct

Tags: c, struct

I have multiple instances of typedef struct box so box box1, box box2 etc.
The members of the struct are length, width, height etc.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int width;
    int height;
} box;

box box1;
box box2;
```

How can I create a function that operates on all the width members of each
box instance? My confusion is how do I pass a pointer to a typedef struct member
that works across all instances of box. I know how to pass a pointer to a specific
instance member like box1.width but how to pass .width and then do

```
box1.width=value;
box2.width=value;
box3.width=value;
```

within the function?

Comment: You can't. Without globals. But don't bother.

Comment: `typedef` only gives a new name to a struct. There is nothing really fancy you can do with it.

Comment: Why not use an array? `SetWidth(size_t arraySize, box array[], int desiredWith)`?

Comment: C++ has a feature called a *pointer-to-member* which allows you to form a pointer to a structure member without an instance, e.g. `int box::*ptr = &box::width; box1->ptr = value; box2->ptr = value;`.  But C doesn't have this feature, so if you can't use C++, then you'll have to use one of the alternative answers provided.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using an array rather than lots of separate instances, e.g.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int width;
    int height;
} Box;

Box boxes[3];                   // array of 3 boxes

for (b = 0; b < 3; b++)         // set `width` field of all boxes to `value`
    boxes[b].width = value;
```

Or, if you really do want to iterate over a number of distinct box variables for some reason then you can initialise an array of pointers instead, e.g.

```
 Box box1;  // 3 separate Box variables
 Box box2;
 Box box3;

 Box *boxes[3] = { &box1, &box2, &box3 };
                                 // array of pointers to box1, box2, box3

 for (b = 0; b < 3; b++)         // set `width` field of all boxes to `value`
    boxes[b]->width = value;
```

Comment: I would suggest the option of creating an array of pointers, in case there are existing boxes you want to iterate over.

Comment: @Elazar: good point - the question is not very clear so I'll add that as an option.

Comment: What I am actually doing is storing instance struct member values to an eeprom. I am just trying to write a function that can store all same members from each instance together. Thanks for all the suggestions. I'll give them a spin.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as field `width` in a typedef (or in a struct) to which you can attach a pointer. The field only physically exists in concrete objects of that type. So, you can't have a pointer to `width` of the struct. You can only have pointers to `box1.width`, `box2.width` and so on.

It is not possible to somehow write a function that would change `width` in all existing objects. More precisely, it is not possible to write a function that will somehow magically enumerate all existing objects of that type and change field `width` in them. It is your responsibility to tell your function which objects you want to change.

In any case, what are you trying to do?

---

If you are trying to write a "setter" function that would be run-time parametrized with the specific field to set, if can be done in C through offsets. For example

```
void set_value(box *box, size_t offset, int value) {
  *(int *) ((char *) box + offset) = value;
}

box box1;
box box2;
box box3;

void set_values(size_t offset, int value)
{
   set_value(&box1, offset, value);
   set_value(&box2, offset, value);
   set_value(&box3, offset, value);
}
```

Now calling

```
set_values(offset_of(box, width), 42);
```

will set widths in `box1`, `box2` and `box3` to `42`, while calling

```
set_values(offset_of(box, height), -5);
```

will set heights in those objects to `-5`.

But, again, it is your responsibility to make sure the function knows which objects it has to change. In the above example I just declared them as file-scope variables. In real-life cases it won't be generally possible.

Comment: I would not recommend type punning like `*(int *) ((char *) box + offset)`, due to the risk of violating strict aliasing rules

Comment: @Joe: There's no type punning here. Accessing an `int` object as an `int` object does not constitute type punning. The fact that access is performed through rather convoluted pointer arithmetic does not change it.

Comment: Until someone has the great idea of using that function to set a float member (not that anyone should...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking for pointers to members, however these are a C++ feature (they could be emulated with `offsetof` although you are likely to run into strict aliasing issues). Unless you are asking for a `.width` which affects *all* instances of `box`, without specifying a specific one. In that case, there is no answer. This would look something like this:

```
// C++ ahead

struct box
{
    int width;
    int height;
};

box boxes[3];

void setGlobalBoxesValue(int value, int box::*member)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(boxes)/sizeof(boxes[0]); ++i)
        boxes[i].*member = value;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    setGlobalBoxesValue(4, &box::width);
    setGlobalBoxesValue(3, &box::height);
    return 0;
}
```

The evil C `offsetof`variant:

```
// C emulation (not typesafe)

#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int width;
    int height;
} box;

box boxes[3];

void setGlobalBoxesValue(int value, size_t memberOffset)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(boxes)/sizeof(boxes[0]); ++i)
        memcpy((char*)(boxes+i) + memberOffset, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    setGlobalBoxesValue(4, offsetof(box, width));
    setGlobalBoxesValue(3, offsetof(box, height));
    return 0;
}
```

If you just want to apply the same operation to multiple instances of box, put them in an array and loop over the array (an array of pointers if they are spread out in memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the `width` field itself to a function. You can, however, pass the offset of it inside the struct.  This is a "dirty" trick, sometimes used in low level programming, but I should not recommend you to use it without a very good reason.

Another option is to use macro. This is probably a bad idea too, but here's how:

```
#define assign(field, value) \
    do { \
        box1.field = value; \
        box2.field = value; \
        box3.field = value; \
    } while (0)
```

and use it like this:

```
assign(width, 5);
```

If you don't know what are the boxes in advance, you can combine it with the array solution suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but

> How can I create a function that operates on all the width members of
>   each box instance? My confusion is how do I pass a pointer to a
>   typedef struct member that works across all instances of box. I know
>   how to pass a pointer to a specific instance member like box1.width
>   but how to pass .width and then do

by creating a function that takes the typedef as an argument you can access width of the struct

```
void foo(box* p)
{
  p->width  .. do something
...
}
```

or if you mean passing an array of box

```
void foo(box* p, int count)
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
     p[i]->width .. do something
    ...
  }
}
```